# Saving multiple records on the same instance in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, primary-key

The code

```
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        SomeClass anObj = new SomeClass();
        anObj.setField(i);
        anObj.setAnotherField("XYZ"+i);
        session.save(anObj);
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

is running with no errors and adding the 10 rows to the table which is what i want. ***field*** is the primary key of ***SomeClass***.

When i move the declaration outside:

```
    SomeClass anObj = new SomeClass();
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        anObj.setField(i);
        anObj.setAnotherField("XYZ"+i);
        session.save(anObj);
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I'm getting an error that "identifier of an instance of SomeClass was altered".

What I "read" from this is that Hibernate is still keeping an eye on the key field of the object after saving it in the database-- that's even after it should, and complaining about it when it comes to commit.

I'd expect that i should be left-alone with the object in the code once i save it and this doesn't make sense.

I'm wondering what's behind it.

Is there a way-- an attribute of **save()** or another save-mode to get around this? I dont want to be re-declaring ***anObj*** at every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is after you call `session.save(anObj)`, the entity object became pesistent -- meaning any subsequent modification to its state will be detected by Hibernate and synchronized to database (sometime down the track).

You can probably save multiple row without re-creating new object by detaching, updating and merging for every new database row, but I'd say this defeats the purpose of using ORM (Object Relational Mapping) in the first place.

I believe hibernate was designed so Java programmer can map a domain object stored in database row as one java object (and vice versa)

Comment: Thx for the answer. Then in this case-- is there a way to tie an object directly to some kind of a "save-mode" so that HN will, while at detecting everything happening to it, make a new save everytime i signal it on the changes on that very same object? Otherwise, all that interference in the core code for not much of a gain.

Comment: I would say you should think about your code's design pattern. Typically hibernate is implemented in a DAO (Data Access Object) classes. You only keep the entity persistent when fetching / updating from the database, otherwise your application always work with a detached instance (no DB operation if object is modified)